# Remove parts of the array with recursive functions Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have the following problem. I have a tree like the following:

[image]

The idea is that when I press the X button, the whole group indicated in the image should be deleted:

[image]

At code level I have an object like the following:

```
  nodeName: 'and',
  nodeID: 1,
  parentNodeID: null,
  conditions: [
    {
      children: [],
      displayDataField: 'Cliente.Centro.Centro',
      order: 1,
      value1: '1',
      parentNodeID: 1,
    },
    {
      order: 2,
      dataField: null,
      condition: null,
      value: null,
      parentNodeID: 1,
      children: [
        {
          nodeName: 'or',
          nodeID: 2,
          parentNodeID: 1,
          conditions: [
            {
              children: [],
              displayDataField: 'Cliente.Datos.Código cliente',
              order: 1,
              value1: '333',
              parentNodeID: 2,
            },
            {
              children: [],
              displayDataField: 'Cliente.Datos.Código cliente',
              order: 2,
              value1: '44',
              parentNodeID: 2,
            },
            {
              order: 3,
              dataField: null,
              condition: null,
              value: null,
              parentNodeID: 2,
              children: [
                {
                  nodeName: 'or',
                  nodeID: 3,
                  parentNodeID: 2,
                  conditions: [
                    {
                      children: [],
                      displayDataField: 'Cliente.Datos.Código cliente',
                      order: 1,
                      value1: '1',
                      parentNodeID: 3,
                    },
                    {
                      children: [],
                      displayDataField: 'Cliente.Datos.Código cliente',
                      order: 2,
                      value1: '30000',
                      parentNodeID: 3,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      children: [],
      displayDataField: 'Cliente.Datos.Fecha de nacimiento',
      order: 3,
      value1: '01/02/1980',
      parentNodeID: 1,
    },
  ],
};
```

In order to understand the object a little better, I attach the following picture:

[image]

The code that I have created to be able to remove that condition is the one that I am going to attach below. But it doesn't manage to do the elimination. In spite of the fact that it has modified for the execution in which we are the array of conditions that it is reading:

```
  onDeleteConditionGroup(eventInfo: { e: any; condition: QueryConditionDto }) {
    this.queryGroupService.deleteConditionGroup(this.globalQuery.query.conditions, eventInfo.condition.parentNodeID);
  }

  deleteConditionGroup(query: QueryConditionDto[], nodeID: number) {
    this._found = false;
    this._queryModified = [];
    this._deleteConditionGroup(query, nodeID);
  }

 private _deleteConditionGroup(query: QueryConditionDto[], nodeID: number, found: boolean = false) {
    query.forEach((item: QueryConditionDto) => {
      if (!found) {
        if (this.queryService.isGroupCondition(item) && item.children[0].nodeID == nodeID) {
          const index = query.findIndex((condition: QueryConditionDto) => condition.children[0]?.nodeID == nodeID);

          // We must choose the preconditions and postconditions
          // The conditions that follow must update their order attribute.
          if (index > -1) {
            const conditionsPrevious = query.filter((condition: QueryConditionDto) => condition.order < query[index].order);
            const conditionsBack = query.filter((condition: QueryConditionDto) => condition.order > query[index].order);

            conditionsBack.forEach((condition: QueryConditionDto) => {
              condition.order = condition.order - 1;
            });

            // We keep the conditions except for the deleted one. BUT IT DOESN'T WORK IT DOESN'T REMOVE ME WTF?!?
            query = conditionsPrevious.concat(conditionsBack);

            this._found = true;
          }
        }
        else if (this.queryService.isGroupCondition(item) && item.children[0].nodeID != nodeID && !this._found) {
          this._deleteConditionGroup(item.children[0].conditions, nodeID);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The code here doesn't seem to be a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  Could you [edit] it to be the smallest amount of code necessary to demonstrate your issue (so, remove anything not directly related to reproducing your problem... and also add everything we need to see it).  Right now it's just code that produces a bunch of errors in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the solution.I need to pass only "this.globalQuery.query" because I had lost the reference of array:
this.queryGroupService.deleteConditionGroup(this.globalQuery.query, eventInfo.condition.parentNodeID);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).